# Unable to RDP into my Windows VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

So, I provisioned this windows VM not quite long ago (less than a year) and all of a sudden I just can't RDP into the VM. I don't have any firewall currently enabled on the VM, port 3389 is opened on NSG level, and there are no rules/policies enabled to block inbound connection whatsoever on the VNet/Subnet.

I have identified the issue as a result of an exclamation mark(!) showing on the network icon of the VM. I know this because I enabled boot diagnostics on the VM. I had encountered this issue sometime in the past but all I did was to restart and the exclamation mark was cleared.

I have restarted the VM multiple times, reset the NIC, attached new NIC, redeployed, and even updated the VM using PowerShell, still I can't RDP into it. I also created a snapshot of the VM, made a disk from the snapshot and deployed a new VM but the issue still persists.

The other VMs in the same VNET/SUBNET are not giving issues.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the followings:

- Try to identify if any windows firewall inside the Azure VM is blocking the inbound and outbound networking traffic. Or any process or antivirus software is disturbing it via checking it on the Task Manager. You can test connection via clicking the **Connection troubleshoot** in the **Support + troubleshooting** blade.
- [Move this VM to a different size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/resize-vm) (usually a larger one). Read [more info](https://www.petri.com/resize-azure-virtual-machine).
- The DNS in this Azure VM may be misconfigured or offline or has lost connectivity with the Internet If you really can connect to the resource with IP address over the Internet. Read more details about [Why Does My Network Icon Have an Exclamation Mark?](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/why-does-my-network-icon-have-an-exclamation-mark/)

Especially, It's recommended to self-diagnose the RDP issue following in the **Diagnose and solve problems** on the Azure virtual machine UI. If it still could not solve your question, you may request MSFT support in the **Support + troubleshooting**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your contributions. I really appreciate. However, going through the suggested steps didn't solve the RDP issue. One thing though, I can't seem to psping the public IP. Anyways, I have requested for support